# Which of those functions are PRFs?

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-function

Assume that $F: \{0,1 \}^n \rightarrow \{0,1 \}^n$ is PRF. Examine if the following functions are PRFs:

$$
\begin{align}
1. \, F_1(k,x) &= F(k,x) \oplus x \\
2. \, F_2(k,x) &= F\left(F(k,0^n), x\right) \\
3. \, F_3(k,x) &= F\left(F(k,0^n), x\right)|| F(k,x)
\end{align}
$$

where $||$ denotes concatenation.

---

### Attempt:

For $1.$ a standard distinguisher would be: $x_1 \oplus x_2 == y_1 \oplus y_2$, where $x_1, x_2$ are two inputs and $y_1, y_2$ are their outputs respectively. So $F_1$ is not a PRF.

For $2.$ I believe that $F(k,0^n) = k'$ acts as a key, so $F_2(k',x) = F(k',x)$ should still be a PRF.

For $3.$ I would say that the concatenation of two PRFs would still be a PRF, since you combine two pseudorandom outputs together to yield $F_3$'s output.

Can you verify my results?

Comment: For 1: $y_1\oplus y_2 = F(k,x_1) \oplus F(k,x_2) \oplus x_1 \oplus x_2$, which will only equal $x_1 \oplus x_2$ if $F(k,x_1) = F(k,x_2)$. For 3. Consider whether there's a way to find out the key used in the left half of the output.

Comment: @Maeher So what can we say about the pseudorandomness of $1.$?

Comment: Hint: if you xor something with a value that's uniformly and independently distributed, what's the distribution of the result?

Comment: After processing your comment, I believe that: for $1.$ since there is a neglible chance that $F(k,x_1) = F(k,x_2)$, then there's no way to distinguish between $F_1$ and a proper random function. For $3.$, if you set $x = 0^n$, the right half of the output is the key used in the left half, so not a PRF. Am I correct?

Comment: 1. That just means that *your* distinguisher doesn't work.You would generally be expected to do a proof by reduction to the security of $F$. 3. sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: Hint for 3: What happens if you query $0^n$?

Comment: @Maeher Using $0^n$ as input you can find the key of the first half. What about $k$, the key of the second half? Isn't that still unknown?

Comment: @SEJPM See my comment above, if you can.

Comment: If someone provide me with an answer that addresses $1.$ and $3.$ I will accept it immediately. Some things still confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have time to go into every detail, but maybe it's enough to get you on the right track.

1.
Is a PRF.

Proof Idea:

Assume we have a distinguisher $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$ distinguishing $F_1$ from a random function with non-negligible probability.
Then we can construct a distinguisher $\mathcal{D}_F$ distinguishing $F$ from a random function with non-negligible probability.

$\mathcal{D}_F$ is given access to an oracle $f(\cdot)$ that's either $F(k, \cdot)$ or a random function $g(\cdot)$.

$\mathcal{D}_F$ runs $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$ and can answer its queries.
When $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$ requests $x$, $\mathcal{D}_{F}$ queries $f$ on $x$ and returns $f(x) \oplus x$ to $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$. This simulates $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$'s queries: when $f$ is $F(k, \cdot)$ we return $F(k, x) \oplus x$, which is exactly $F_1(k, x)$.

When $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$ is done, we replicate its output: when it says it's talking to $F_1$ (output = 1), $\mathcal{D}_F$ outputs the same. When it says it's talking to a random function (output = 0), $\mathcal{D}_F$ outputs the same.

You would now have to prove that the advantage:
$|\Pr[\mathcal{D}_F^{F(k, \cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr[\mathcal{D}_F^{g(\cdot)}(1^n) = 1]|$
of $\mathcal{D}_F$ is non-negligible, using the assumption that the advantage of $\mathcal{D}_{F_1}$ is non-negligible.

This last part is usually the hard part, where errors can come up silently, so be careful about skipping steps or making invalid assumptions.

2.

Is a PRF.

Intuitively, the question of whether this is a PRF seems to reduce to whether an adversary can predict $F(k, 0^n)$. However, a function where this is possible for non-negligibly many $k$ is not a PRF.

3.

Not a PRF.

We can construct a distinguisher $\mathcal{D}$ with non-negligible advantage. $\mathcal{D}$ is given access to $f(\cdot)$, which is either $F_3(k, \cdot)$ or a random function. I denote the first half of $z$ as $z_L$ and the second half of $z$ as $z_R$.

1. $\mathcal{D}$ queries $y^0 = f(0)$
2. $\mathcal{D}$ computes $y^1 = F(y^0_R, x)$ for some random $x$.
3. $\mathcal{D}$ queries $y^2 = f(x)$
4. If $y^1 = y^2_L$, $\mathcal{D}$ outputs that $f$ is $F_3$.
5. Otherwise, $\mathcal{D}$ outputs that $f$ is a random function.

$\mathcal{D}$ has non-negligible advantage: if $f$ is $F_3$, then $y^1 = y^2_L$:

$y^1 = F(y^0_R, x) = F(f(0^n), x) = F(F(k, 0^n), x)$

$y^2_L = f(x)_L = F_3(k, x)_L = F(F(k, 0^n), x)$

The probability that this holds when $f$ is a random function is negligible.

Hope I could help!

Comment: I'm still uncertain about the claim 2, and dubious about the argument made. What about if there's a random-like subset $\mathcal S$ of $\{0,1\}$, and when $k\in\mathcal S$ then $F(k,x)=0^n$, else if $x=0^n$ then $F(k,x)$ is a pseudo-random element of $\mathcal S$, else $F(k,x)$ is a true PRF of $(k,x)$? Now $F_2(k,x)$ is always $0^n$, yet an adversary can't predict $F(k,0^n)$.

Comment: That's true, the adversary doesn't need to predict - after all it's a distinguishing game. I was only giving some intuition on how this proof could be approached, but I cannot even guarantee my answer is correct, since I have not proved it. (cont...)

Comment: As you say, $F$ can have some weak keys $k \in S$, where the output of $F(k, x) = 0^n$. However, $S$ cannot be noticeably large, otherwise $F$ wouldn't be a PRF, since the adversary would be able to easily determine that the output is $0^n$ for all $x$ for noticeably many $k$. Therefore, $S$ must be some negligible fraction of the key domain, and will give the adversary only negligible advantage.

Comment: Notice that my weak key set has size such that it's chosen with negligible probability $2^{-n/2}$, thus $F(k,x)$ can only be distinguished from random by one applying the _algorithm_ implementing $F$ (feeding the result obtained from the oracle queried with $x=0^k$ into the key input of that algorithm). If the definition of the PRF challenge allows that, then indeed $F_2$ is demonstrably a PRF when $F$ is, otherwise my counterexampel $F$ seems to be a PRF, but definitely $F_2$ is not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on some things: Do you mean that $|S| = 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$? If the definition of the PRF game (?) allows the adversary to evaluate $F(k, x)$ for some adversary chosen $k$ and $x$, then $F_2$ is a PRF? Could you explain why $F_2$ would not be a PRF if that's not the case?

Comment: From what I gather: In the PRF game the adversary doesn't know or choose the key $k$ - it is sampled uniform randomly. Therefore, the weak keys would only be sampled with negligible probability, and the adversary would play against a random function (i.e. $k$ is not weak) with overwhelming probability.

Comment: As you have seen, I made a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86364/555) out of it. I'm (now totally) convinced by the answer I got, and that the $G$ there (a refined version of the $F$ above) is not a PRF, for the standard or any sensible definition of that. I'm still trying to find how to make as distinguisher for $F$ out of a distinguisher for $F_2$, though. The only thing I can think of is using the same, but when I try to do the math in the K&L formalism, that seems to fails.

Answer (score 4):

Since @fgrieu was interested in question 2, I'm going to break with site policy and give a full answer for that part, even though this is almost certainly homework.

**Theorem.**
Let $F : \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a PRF. Then, $F_2 : \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$, defined as
$$F_2(k,x) := F(F(k,0^n),x)$$
is also a PRF.

Before we give a formal proof, let's build some intuition why this should be the case. Note that the inner invocation of $F$ is not on some part of the input, but instead on a constant (i.e., $0^n$). This means that once we fix the key $k$, the key used by the outer invocation of $F$ for *all* evaluations of $F_2$ is a fixed key $k' := F(k,0^n)$. Since $k$ is not used elsewhere in the construction, $k'$ should, by the security of the underlying PRF, be indistinguishable from a uniformly random key $k''$, as long as $k$ is chosen uniformly at random. This would mean than an oracle evaluating $F_2(k,\cdot)$ and an oracle evaluating $F(k,\cdot)$ should in fact be indistinguishable. Since $F(k,\cdot)$ is already known to be indistinguishable from a uniformly chosen random function $f(\cdot)$ and indistinguishablity (in the asymptotic sense) is transitive, it would follow that $F_2$ must also be a PRF.

So let's formalize this intuition.

**Proof.** Let $A$ be an arbitrary PPT algorithm with
$$\Bigl|\Pr_k[A^{F_2(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr_f[A^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|=\epsilon(n).$$
We are looking to give a negligible upper bound for $\epsilon$. To do this we will prove a series of claims.

**Claim 1.** $\Bigl|\Pr\limits_k[A^{F(F(k,0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr\limits_{f}[A^{F(f(0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr| \leq \mathsf{negl}(n)$

Consider the following adversary $B$ against the PRF security of $F$.
Upon input $1^n$ and given access to an oracle, $B$ queries $0^n$ to the oracle an receives back a value $k'$. It then invokes $A$ on input $1^n$. Whenever $A$ sends a query $x$ to its oracle, $B$ responds by computing $y:=F(k',x)$. Eventually, $A$ will output a bit $b$ which $B$ also outputs.

It is easy to see that $$\Pr_k[B^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1] = \Pr_k[A^{F(F(k,0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1]$$ and $$\Pr_f[B^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1] = \Pr_f[A^{F(f(0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1].$$
Further, since $F$ is a secure PRF, it must hold that
$$\Bigl|\Pr_k[B^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1]-\Pr_f[B^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|\leq \mathsf{negl}(n)$$
and the claim follows.

**Claim 2.** $\Pr\limits_{f}[A^{F(f(0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1] = \Pr\limits_{k}[A^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1]$

To see that this is the case, it is easiest to think of $f$ as being lazily sampled when queried. Since $f$ is only ever invoked on $0^n$, sampling $f$ is equivalent to simply sampling $f(0^n)$ once as a uniformly random value $k\in \{0,1\}$, which is identical to the right hand side.

**Claim 3.** $\Bigl|\Pr_{k}[A^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr_{f}[A^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr| \leq \mathsf{negl}(n)$

This claim is in fact just a restatement of the assumption that $F$ is a PRF and thus follows trivially.

Using the triangle inequality, we can conclude
\begin{align}
  \epsilon(n) =&\quad \Bigl|\Pr_k[A^{F_2(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr_f[A^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|\\
  \leq&\quad\Bigl|\Pr\limits_k[A^{F(F(k,0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr\limits_{f}[A^{F(f(0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|\\ 
&+ \Bigl|\Pr\limits_{f}[A^{F(f(0^n),\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr\limits_{k}[A^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|\\ 
&+ \Bigl|\Pr_{k}[A^{F(k,\cdot)}(1^n)=1] - \Pr_{f}[A^{f(\cdot)}(1^n)=1]\Bigr|\\
&\leq 2\cdot\mathsf{negl}(n)
\end{align}
and the theorem statement immediately follows.$\tag*{$\square$}$